# React.js How Do You Concatenate Dynamic Text From State

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please consider the following:

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    this.handleText1Change = this.handleText1Change.bind(this);
    this.handleText2Change = this.handleText2Change.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        text1 : '',
        text2 : '',
        text3 : `Type something into one of the text fields`
        }
    }

    handleText1Change = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({text1: e.target.value})
    }

    handleText2Change = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({text2: e.target.value})
    }

    render() {
        return(
        <div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight mb-3">
              <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">
                  <label for="text1-box"><h4>Text1</h4></label><br />
                  <textarea 
                    type="text" 
                    value={this.state.text1} 
                    onChange={this.handleText1Change} />
              </div>
              <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">
                  <label for="text2-box"><h4>Text2</h4></label><br />
                  <textarea 
                    type="text" 
                    value={this.state.text2} 
                    onChange={this.handleText2Change} />
              </div>

              <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">
                  <label for="result"><h4>Combined Result</h4></label>
                  <br />
                  <p>{this.state.text1 ?
                      this.state.text1 :
                      this.state.text2 ?
                      this.state.text2 :
                      this.state.text1 && this.state.text2 ? 
                      this.state.text1 + this.state.text2 :
                      this.state.text3 }</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Tho I can display dynamic text if typing into Text1's or Text2's textarea, it appears unable to combine the dynamic text per the condition `this.state.text1 && this.state.text2`.

I want to type any text into BOTH textarea boxes and get the combined text `this.state.text1 + this.state.text2` (as specified in my ternary statement).

But it's not working and it only seems to be rendering OR but not AND.

How can I make it dynamically render concatenated dynamic text? Is this possible?

To be more clear, if I type 'apple' into the first textarea and 'banana' into the second textarea, I want it to display 'applebanana' but it's not doing so and it only gives 'apple' or 'banana' and fails to render 'applebanana' in Combined Result.

Comment: You will never reach to the `this.state.text1 && this.state.text2` condition if any of `this.state.text1 or this.state.text2` is true because you have these condition before `this.state.text1 && this.state.text2`, so you may want to change there order to get it fixed

Comment: Also don't use nested ternary it is really uneasy for eyes, use a function and inside function use simple if else conditions and call that function in jsx

Comment: You are a genius! After I put the && condition first, it totally worked. Thank you so much! I've been trying to figure this out all day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your code is order of conditions, You will never reach to the `this.state.text1 && this.state.text2` condition if any of `this.state.text1 or this.state.text2` is true because you have these condition `this.state.text1` or `this.state.text2` before `this.state.text1 && this.state.text2`, you need to get `&&` condition before these,

Also don't use nested ternary it is really uneasy for eyes, use a function and inside function use simple if else conditions and call that function in jsx

---

```
function giveMeText(state) {
  if(state.text1 && state.text2){
    return state.text1 + state.text2
  }
  // so on
}
```

---

call the function inside JSX like this

```
<div> giveMeText(this.state) </div>
```